# Where can I find some good online resources on asp.net mvc 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to learn the new features in asp.net mvc 2. Where online can I learn all the features of asp.net mvc 2

Answer (score 1):

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Basics-Introduction-by-Scott-Hanselman/

and then

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/matthijs/ASPNET-MVC-2-Ninja-Black-Belt-Tips-by-Scott-Hanselman/

Best videos out there by a mile! :)

Also check out the series over at www.tekpub.com, although that isn't free ,but definitely worth the price :)

Answer (score 0):

HI,

[this](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/what-is-new-in-aspnet-mvc) seems a good place to start.

All new features in asp.net mvc 2 are enlisted and are described in detail.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

While it's paid content, it's definitely very high quality and covers a huge breadth of information:

http://tekpub.com/preview/aspmvc